# Where do you store State in this scenario

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular RxJs State Management and have 3 levels of abstraction:

1- DataService (like userService) that do the CRUD job and some automatic calculation. (ex: after reading their user list from de HTTP call, calculate the number of administrators and return the number

2- FacadeService (like FacadeUserService). Consume several DataService, contain all the logic code.

3- Views: Consume only the corresponding FacadeService

Where do I store de state?
It is OK to have some state on the DataService (list of users + couple of automatic calculation), and have some other state data in the Facade Service?

EDIT1
I upodate my question with the link I make in my FacadeService to get the users + sont informations on these user (parentIds)
This code are in my FacadeConstructor and update the local Facade Store with the user Data service.

```
        this.moduleService.modules$.subscribe(modules => {
            let parentIds = this.moduleService.parentIdsValues
            this.store.next({..._state, modules, parentIds})
        })
```

Comment: For now the only way I found, is to subscribe to the users$ observable from the FacadeService constructor (and if I need the administrator count too, I get it by this.usersService.AdministratorCountValue inside de subscribe call). In that way, I can call from the facadeService the UserService.LoadUsers() that call HTTP inside UsersService then next the users$. But It seems weird code...

Comment: So a Facade is a bridge to connect to other services, my 2cent is you save the state in the services, a bridge should be a bridge. I'm not really understand your comment above as Facade.getAllUser will call UserService.getUsers -> return observer as usual.

Comment: thank for reply, I updated the question with a code sample of what I currently do in my Facade constructor.